# Download image by API

Tags: python, django

I always use request.get method, but now need to upload image on hosting by the api. I get this error: TypeError: must be str, not InMemoryUploadedFile. Im understand, what arises this error. How do upload an image in the code?

```
data = request.FILES['avatar']
api = 'http://uploads.ru/api?upload=' + data
upload_image = requests.post(api)
respons = upload_image
```

Comment: I think you should spend some more time with this problem.  The error is indicating the data var is not a string, so you cannot concatenate when attempting to define the api variable.

Comment: Why does the title of this question have not "upload" but "download"?

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` module takes a `files` argument for uploading `multipart` encoded files to a URL.

change your code to this:

```
file_data = {'filename': data}
r = requests.post(api, files=[file_data])
```

I'll probably write the file to disk, before trying to upload it. so you don't lose everything if something goes wrong.

Comment: I get error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). Response: <MultiValueDict: {'avatar': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: images.jpeg (image/jpeg)>]}>

Comment: I resolved problem. Thanks!                                                                         data = request.FILES,
api = 'http://uploads.ru/api?upload=',
r = requests.post(api, files=data)